# Multiple locals on one line?

Tags: syntax, lua

Consider the following Lua code:

```
local var1, var2;
```

Is `var2` a local variable here? Or is only `var1` a local?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Both are local.

Answer (score 26):

Both variables are local, and both are given a value of `nil`.

To assign them to 2 different values, simply:

```
local var1,var2 = 1,2
```

Comment: All variables are `nil` unless you give them some other value. That first line doesn't do anything different than the line in the original question. You're explicitly putting `nil` into var1 and implicitly putting it into `var`. If it worked the way you're describing, then `var1, var2 = 1` would put `1` into both variables. This is not the case. `var1` would be `1` and `var2` would be `nil`.